# Angular.js: Combine Restangular and oauth-ng

Tags: angularjs, oauth, restangular

We have built an RestFul API implementing OAuth 2.0

Now I want to connect an AngularJS frontend using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) and [oauth-ng](https://github.com/andreareginato/oauth-ng)

**But how can I get both to interact regarding the oauth token?**

Oauth-ng should handle login/logout and token refreshing. 
Restangular should fetch the access_token from oauth-ng to send the token with all requests.

My current code is implemented like this.

```
angular
    .module('myapp', ['oauth','restangular'/* ... */ ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider,RestangularProvider,AccessToken) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
                template: '',
                controller: function ($location, AccessToken) {
                    var hash = $location.path().substr(1);
                    AccessToken.setTokenFromString(hash);
                    console.log(AccessToken); //THIS WORKS
                    $location.path('/');
                    $location.replace();
                }
            })
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: true
        }).hashPrefix('!');

        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://myapi.local/');
        // next line throws error
        RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AccessToken.get()});
    });
```

But this code throws an error **"Unknown provider: AccessToken".**

Seems like "AccessToken" is not yet available at the config stage.
But I do not want to implement this general function in every controller again and again.

What would be a good way to connect both modules?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AccessToken var is not injected in the scope you're using it. 
Did you try moving setting the Token for Restangular to the point where you fulfill your promise. Example:

```
angular
.module('myapp', ['oauth','restangular'/* ... */ ])
.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider,RestangularProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
            template: '',
            controller: function ($location, AccessToken) {
                var hash = $location.path().substr(1);
                AccessToken.setTokenFromString(hash);
                RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AccessToken.get()});
                console.log(AccessToken); //THIS WORKS
                $location.path('/');
                $location.replace();
            }
        })
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: true
    }).hashPrefix('!');

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://myapi.local/');
});
```